# How to create dot circle in css?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a calendar which have disabled dates , I want one of my disabled date to contain a small dot .

Here is visualizaition on how it suppose to look
[image]

Here is html:

```
   <p-calendar [inline]="true" [disabledDates]="restrictedBookingDates" [minDate]="minimumDate" tabindex="0"
          readonlyInput="true">
            <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
                <span  class="dot" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: (date.day ==19) ? '#348db2' : 'inherit'}"   
                >{{date.day}}</span>
            </ng-template>
        </p-calendar>
```

this is my css so far:

```
.dot::after {
  content: '';
  background: #f00;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

> **UPDATE**

Here is the class for disbaled dates returned from calendar:

```
<a class="ui-state-default ng-tns-c2-0 ui-state-disabled ng-star-inserted" draggable="false" href="#" ng-reflect-klass="ui-state-default" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" style="
    background:  red;
">
}--><div _ngcontent-c1="" class="dot ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-color: rgb(52, 141, 178);">19</div></a>
```

Unfortunately this does not work , google couldnt help too. so am stuck,

What am I missing in my code? any help suggestion will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.dot {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;

}

.ui-state-disabled::after {
  content: '';
  background: #f00;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot ui-state-disabled"></div>
```

If you add a class: `ui-state-disabled` only to the element you want, it will work

Comment: Hii Damian this adds in all dates not on specified date as I want,

Comment: your specified date has a class ?

Comment: have a class as per question I asked goes by the name dot .  check the html I provided

Comment: The code I'm showing will work on all elements with class `dot`. You may render a class only for the desired elements

Comment: Ye it display dot but on all dates I just want on single date not all

Comment: You need to add a class only to that single date

Comment: .ui-state-disabled class for disabled date here u got

Comment: okay I will check i have updated the question and added the fuhll returned class for disabled date.

Comment: and here is the live demo in heroku for reference you can check it urself https://proexebookingapp.herokuapp.com/

Comment: your answer still display bullet but for all dates not for disabled dates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174606/discussion-between-damian-peralta-and-kaczka-pojebana).